# ADODB.Recordset returns with incorrect data?

Tags: sql-server, vb6, adodb, recordset

I have an ADO.Recordset object that is able to successfully connect to the database and pull data. However, the data that is in the database vs what is being retrieved by the object is incorrect.

For example, if I take the exact query that is in the command parameter in the Recordset and execute it in Sql Server Management Studio, the RANK in SSMS is 170 but the data returned in code from the object says it is 140.

Has anyone run across a situation like this before? I can't figure out why this is happening.

This involves a search box where the user is trying to search for a product and the script is trying to find the product that the user most likely wants to find.

```
SELECT tbl.RANK as rk, a.*, CA.* FROM FREETEXTTABLE
   ([ab_fts],([cpn],[cd],[mas],[ac],[ttr],[nemo],[man]),'tester',1000) tbl
INNER JOIN [qws] a on tbl.[key] = a.wid 
INNER JOIN catad CA ON (CA.cgid = a.cgid) 
ORDER BY rk DESC
```

Comment: Please show the VB6 code.

Comment: I used Sql Profiler and the Immediate Window in Visual Studio 2013 to see what the search criteria is before the query is sent by the Ado.Recordset and when the sql instance receives it. When I use the immediate window, the search criteria is correct, but when the sql instance receives it the criteria is different. Has anyone heard about this?

Comment: rstCategory.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
rstCategory.Open(sSearchSpeeeeed, dbsMainAlt, adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly)
            rstCategory.ActiveConnection = Nothing